# How to access the instance when prototyping with constructor functions?

Tags: javascript, oop, constructor, prototype

I'm extending a constructor class' functionality via the `prototype` method, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to access the soon-to-be instance of the constructor class.

Lets say we have the following class:

```
Bla = function()
{
    this.a = 5;
}
```

Simple enough. Now, I will extend it with a very simple method...

`Bla.prototype.f = function(){console.log("Abdf.")};`

`new Bla().f(); //Logs "Abdf as expected."`

But, what if I wanted to access the `a` property (5)? Say I am trying to extend the constructor class like this:

`Bla.prototype.f2 = function(b){return b * here_are_the_problems.a};`

Apparently using `this` refers to something else. What should I use instead?

Comment: Use `this.a`. Works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/bNwuU/

Comment: Huh, really? OK then, I messed up while trying out examples in the console, apparently.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Prototyping in Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11066328/prototyping-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `this` to refer to the object on which the method was called...

```
console.log(this.a);
```

There are several ways the value of `this` can be set. One is that it generally refers to the object on which the function was called if the function was called as a method of the object.

```
Bla = function()
{
    this.a = 5;
}


Bla.prototype.f = function(){console.log(this.a)};

var bla = new Bla();

bla.f(); //Logs 5
```

So you can see that since `f` was called as a method of the instance of `Bla` referenced by the `bla` variable, the value of `this` in `f` will be set to refer to that same object.

Comment: Special note: If you're using the object method as an event handler (and in other circumstances, but event handling is the most common situation), the method will usually be called in the element's context. I.e. in `element.onclick = bla_instance.some_method;`, the `this` keyword will actually refer to the element and not the `bla_instance` (same if you use jQuery to bind events).

Comment: @Flambino: Yes, though I wouldn't say it uses the element's "scope". Scope is a very separate issue from `this`, which refers to calling context. But yes, there's no binding of the calling context to the original object *(unless you use `Function.prototype.bind()` to create one)*.

Comment: you're right, I meant to write "context" - fixed my comment. And yes, `.bind` (or `$.proxy` if you're using jQuery in an older browser that doesn't support bind natively) is the fix. Should've mentioned that too, I suppose :-P

Comment: @Flambino: There are just too many aspects to the semantics of `this`. A person can say too little, and leave holes, or too much, and fall away from the original point. `:)`

Comment: Yeah, explaining `this` can quickly go off the track. But I figured that event handling is a common source of context-confusion, so I thought I'd better mention it. Especially if the original question came about because of `this.a` _seemingly_ not working right :)

Answer (score 2):

Use the `this` keyword to access any instance property or methods.  `this` represents the instance.  Since `a` is an instance property and `prototype` methods are instance methods, it is accessible in the `prototype`.

```
Bla = function() {
    this.a = 5;
};
Bla.prototype.foo = function () {
   console.log( this.a );
}

var x = new Bla;
x.foo(); // logs 5
​
```

However, if we add a method directly to Bla...

```
Bla.bar = function () {
   console.log( this.a ); // ERRORRRRR
}
```

Because bar is not an instance (`prototype`) method. In this case, it's a `static method` of `Bla` and doesn't have an instance and `this` refers to the function `Bla.bar`, in which case doesn't have a property `a`

Comment: You should refer to `a` as a property of the object, not as a variable. Any actual variable in the `Bla` constructor will be not directly reachable from prototyped methods.

Comment: @Trevor, what is a "`static method`"?

Comment: A static method is a method of a class that doesn't require an instance and doesn't have access to instance variables. You would typically write one of these to create an instance of the class or a method related to the class type.