# Why is array.prototype.slice() so slow on sub-classed arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance-testing, subclass, v8

In node v14.3.0, I discovered (while doing some coding work with very large arrays) that sub-classing an array can cause `.slice()` to slow down by a factor 20x.  While, I could imagine that there might be some compiler optimizations around a non-subclassed array, what I do not understand at all is how `.slice()` can be more than 2x slower than just manually copying elements from one array to another.  That does not make sense to me at all.  Anyone have any ideas?  Is this a bug or is there some aspect to this that would/could explain it?

For the test, I created a 100,000,000 unit array filled with increasing numbers.  I made a copy of the array with `.slice()` and I made a copy manually by then iterating over the array and assigning values to a new array.  I then ran those two tests for both an `Array` and my own empty subclass `ArraySub`.  Here are the numbers:

```
Running with Array(100,000,000)
sliceTest: 436.766ms
copyTest: 4.821s

Running with ArraySub(100,000,000)
sliceTest: 11.298s
copyTest: 4.845s
```

The manual copy is about the same both ways.  The `.slice()` copy is 26x slower on the sub-class and more than 2x slower than the manual copy.  Why would that be?

And, here's the code:

```
// empty subclass for testing purposes
class ArraySub extends Array {

}

function test(num, cls) {
    let name = cls === Array ? "Array" : "ArraySub";
    console.log(`--------------------------------\nRunning with ${name}(${num})`);
    // create array filled with unique numbers
    let source = new cls(num);
    for (let i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        source[i] = i;
    }

    // now make a copy with .slice()
    console.time("sliceTest");
    let copy = source.slice();
    console.timeEnd("sliceTest");

    console.time("copyTest");
    // these next 4 lines are a lot faster than this.slice()
    const manualCopy = new cls(num);
    for (let [i, item] of source.entries()) {
        manualCopy[i] = item;
    }
    console.timeEnd("copyTest");
}

[Array, ArraySub].forEach(cls => {
    test(100_000_000, cls);
});
```

FYI, there's a similar result in this [jsperf.com test](https://jsperf.com/array-slice-on-subclass/1) when run in the Chrome browser.  Running the jsperf in Firefox shows a similar trend, but not as much of a difference as in Chrome.

Comment: My guess is that the inner loop of `slice()` is checking for getter/setter methods.

Comment: @Barmar - Is there a reason, `.slice()` would have to do more work than the manual assignment loop?

Comment: There's probably an optimization being done for the array indexing that isn't happening inside slice.

Comment: The V8 code [here](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/master/src/builtins/array-slice.tq) makes reference to `FastSlice()`, but is beyond what I can follow.

Comment: Any difference when swapping the order to `[ArraySub, Array]`?

Comment: Just to throw out there an alternative that should outperform both: `Object.values(source)`

Comment: @Ry - I don't see any meaningful difference with the order.  I also ran 5 different lengths for each class with the 100_000_000 being last for each.  Got same results if I switch `ArraySub` to be first instead of last.

Comment: Perhaps the subclass elements are being treated as individual object key/value entries while the array entries are being treated as one piece of contiguous memory.

Comment: repl.it so you guys can test for yourselves if you don't have nodejs locally https://repl.it/repls/SvelteDeadlyGlueware  I think @xdhmoore is probably right; optimizations for underlying flat array probably can't be used when using the subclass and `this`.

Comment: @user120242 - But, none of that explains why `.slice()` on the subclass is substantially SLOWER than just a manual one-by-one copy of each value from one array to another.  You can re-implment `.slice()` in plain Javascript and it will be faster than the built-in implmentation (when operating on a sub-class).  Something seems wrong there.

Comment: JavaScript does some JIT optimization of array indexing and property accesses. These optimizations are presumably not being done inside the slice() method.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

V8 developer here. What you're seeing is fairly typical:

The built-in `.slice()` function for regular arrays is heavily optimized, taking all sorts of shortcuts and specializations (it even goes as far as using `memcpy` for arrays containing only numbers, hence copying more than one element at a time using your CPU's vector registers!). That makes it the fastest option.

Calling `Array.prototype.slice` on a custom object (like a subclassed array, or just `let obj = {length: 100_000_000, foo: "bar", ...}`) doesn't fit the restrictions of the fast path, so it's handled by a generic implementation of the `.slice` builtin, which is much slower, but can handle anything you throw at it. This is not JavaScript code, so it doesn't collect type feedback and can't get optimized dynamically. The upside is that it gives you the same performance every time, no matter what. This performance is not actually *bad*, it just pales in comparison to the optimizations you get with the alternatives.

Your own implementation, like all JavaScript functions, gets the benefit of dynamic optimization, so while it naturally can't have any fancy shortcuts built into it right away, it can adapt to the situation at hand (like the type of object it's operating on). That explains why it's faster than the generic builtin, and also why it provides consistent performance in both of your test cases. That said, if your scenario were more complicated, you could probably pollute this function's type feedback to the point where it becomes slower than the generic builtin.

With the `[i, item] of source.entries()` approach you're coming close to the spec behavior of `.slice()` very concisely at the cost of some overhead; a plain old `for (let i = 0; i < source.length; i++) {...}` loop would be about twice as fast, even if you add an `if (i in source)` check to reflect `.slice()`'s "HasElement" check on every iteration.

---

More generally: you'll probably see the same general pattern for many other JS builtins -- it's a natural consequence of running on an optimizing engine for a dynamic language. As much as we'd love to just make everything fast, there are two reasons why that won't happen:

(1) Implementing fast paths comes at a cost: it takes more engineering time to develop (and debug) them; it takes more time to update them when the JS spec changes; it creates an amount of code complexity that quickly becomes unmanageable leading to further development slowdown and/or functionality bugs and/or security bugs; it takes more binary size to ship them to our users and more memory to load such binaries; it takes more CPU time to decide which path to take before any of the actual work can start; etc. Since none of those resources are infinite, we'll always have to choose where to spend them, and where not.

(2) Speed is fundamentally at odds with flexibility. Fast paths are fast because they get to make restrictive assumptions. Extending fast paths as much as possible so that they apply to as many cases as possible is part of what we do, but it'll always be easy for user code to construct a situation that makes it impossible to take the shortcuts that make a fast path fast.

Comment: What this also shows is how good the dynamic optimizations are.

Comment: Thx for responding.  Why does the fact that you subclassed the array disqualify it from the built-in `.slice()` optimizations?  It's the exact same array data structure.  Nothing has changed there at all.  In my real world example, there are just a few extra methods in the prototype chain and in my test example above, there aren't even more methods in the prototype chain.  Wouldn't it be doable to extend the optimization to a subclass like this?  Or just not considered worth it to even investigate?  Or some edge case trouble?

Comment: I'm rapidly coming to the conclusion that I'm better off modifying the built-in `Array` prototype to add methods rather than sub-classing which until a 20x speed difference showed itself seemed like a bad thing to do.  This definitely creates a quandary.  Can't use typical OO design principles without losing meaningful performance.  The fast path performance is appreciated, but seeing it disappear just because you used a basic OO sub-class that shouldn't really interfere seems problematic too.

Comment: FYI, changing the manual copy `for` loop to `for (let i = 0; i < len; i++)` boosted its speed another 30%, making it that much faster than `.slice()` on the Array sub-class.  So, I guess either plain old `for` loops are meaningfully faster than iterators or I again stumbled into a fast path optimization.

Comment: The `.slice` fast path doesn't handle subclasses because subclasses _might_ invalidate the assumptions it relies on. Extending it, or adding another slightly slower fast path for subclasses may well be feasible -- but is it worth the cost? Do you see a measurable performance difference in real code? And if yes, how many such real apps are there? Microbenchmarks are pretty meaningless; optimizing for microbenchmarks (in your code, or in the engine) is often counter-productive for real-world code, which is what matters for users.

Comment: Modifying `Array.prototype` also causes various fast paths not to be taken any more and as such is not recommended, but you can certainly do it if you like, and/or if your measurements indicate that it actually works out better for your case. Again, please measure with real code, not with microbenchmarks. -- Regarding loops, `for..of` loops nowadays are generally competitive with classic `for(...; i < len; ...)` loops. Going via `.entries` is a detour that has a cost.

Comment: @jmrk - I only noticed the performance difference because it was relevant in real world code.  I'm doing some processing of very large arrays in node.js and the 20x difference changed a 10 second operation into a 200 second (over 3 minutes) operation.  I noticed. 
I'd be curious what relevant assumptions might be invalidated by a sub-class?  Once the `.slice()` method call has been received, everything done in service of that request can be internal to the implementation.  FYI, I never received notification of your comments so just now saw them - sorry for the delay.

Comment: For example, the fast path relies on the assumption that there are no elements anywhere on the object's prototype chain. For the default (unmodified) Array prototype that's guaranteed; for random subclasses it would have to be checked every time, so at best that'd be a medium-fast path.

Comment: Yeah, but the bigger question is why is the non-fast path, 2.5x slower than just creating the new object yourself and looping to copy things over.  That's the most unfortunate part.  Apparently the interpreter is better at optimizing my code than it is its own.  There are huge opportunities here to either expand the fast path or make the slow path not so ridiculously slow.

Comment: @jmrk What about changing the prototypes on the fly using Object.setPrototypeOf? I created a repl of the original question's source code. Adding a slice function to ArraySub and changing the prototype to Array then back again makes the performance comparable. Any thoughts on this approach? https://replit.com/@SpencerEvans4/SvelteDeadlyGlueware#index.js

Comment: Nevermind. The comparable speed is only in the repl nodejs environment. It totally fails in chrome and runs even slower.