# How to find if a method belongs to super or - Extending Array and Testing with ES6

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, oop, ecmascript-6, es6-class

I'm new to OOP in ES6 and trying to understand how to extend Array so i can create pipelines. I'm starting with a simple case of extending `Array` ad overriding `Array.filter`, and expecting `result.hasOwnProperty("filter")` to be `true`...  but it's not:

So how do you test that the method filter now lives in the Wordlist class?

```js
export class Wordlist extends Array{
  constructor(...args){
    super(...args)
  }

  filter(...args){
    console.log("filtering")
    return super.filter(...args)
  }
}

// test
describe.only('Wordlist.filter', ()=>{
  it('should filter an array', ()=>{
    const wordlist = new Wordlist('hello', 'rhubarb')
    const result = wordlist.filter(word => word === 'rhubarb')

    expect(result.length).toEqual(1) // pass
    expect(result).toEqual(["rhubarb"]) // pass
    expect(result.hasOwnProperty('filter')).toBe(true) // should pass but doesnt!!! 
    expect(result.hasOwnProperty('reduce')).toBe(false) // passes
  })
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The misunderstanding is about how `.hasOwnProperty()` works.  This returns a boolean that indicates whether an object directly contains a specific property.  In your case, you are defining a property for the class which puts the new `.filter()` property on the object's prototype which means that **the `.filter()` property is NOT directly on the object, but is inherited from the object's prototype**.

So, by definition when the property is only on the prototype, `.hasOwnProperty()` will return `false`.

If you want to see if `result` is actually a `Wordlist` object, then you can use:

```
 result instanceof Wordlist   // should be true
```

to test for that.  You could also do this:

```
 Object.getPrototypeOf(result).hasOwnProperty('filter')   // should be true
```

And, to make sure it's not the same `.filter` as an array has, you could check this:

```
result.filter !== [].filter   // should be false
```

Comment: Thank you, yes, i want to ensure it's an instance of wordlist and wordlist has it's own method, filter, which is different from Array.filter

Comment: @fotoflo - Well, just check `result instanceof Wordlist` and then you can check `result.filter !== [].filter` if you want to make sure `result.filter` is not the regular Array `.filter()` method.  That will show that it's both a `Wordlist` object and it's got a different filter method.

Comment: @fotoflo - See the edits in my answer.

Comment: @fotoflo - FYI, subclassing an Array and/or replacing methods can lose all sorts of performance optimizations (26x slower for one such method) for the subclassed array even though there appears to be no reason for such performance loss.  See [Why is array.prototype.slice so slow on a subclassed Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62184501/why-is-array-prototype-slice-so-slow-on-sub-classed-arrays).